# Stripe different plans

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I got stripe up and running, however I have 3 different payment plans.
I'd like to capture what plan they clicked on, and use that to connect them to their right plan id.

This is what my form looks like:

```
<%= form_tag charges_path, id: "payment-form" do %>
  <span class="payment-errors"></span>


  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Card Number</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number" maxlength="20" />
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>CVC</span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc" maxlength="4"/>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month" maxlength="2"/>
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year" maxlength="4"/>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit Payment</button>
<% end %>
```

I link to them like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Start Your Free Trial', new_charge_path(:plan_id => 1) %>
```

and the controller looks like this:

```
def create
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => 'exaimple@stripe.com',
    :plan => plan_id,
    :card  => params[:stripeToken]
  )
  current_user.update_attributes(:stripe_customer_token => customer.id)
  redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Successfully subscribed'
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to charges_path
  end
```

which results in the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `plan_id'
```